# Spring finding multiple bean definition error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code for my Spring-based web project:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("mycontroller")
public class MyObjectController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
// Code omitted
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mydao")
    private MyDao mydao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mydao2")
    private MyDao2 mydao2;

// Code omitted
}
```

**Context.xml (Spring):**

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />    

<beans:bean id="myService" class="com.mycompany.serviceimpl.MyServiceImpl" />
```

However it throws this error:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.mycompany.service.MyService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [myService, myServiceImpl]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bean **is** defined twice, here (`@Service` annotation, results in registering `myServiceImpl` bean):

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
```

and here (in `Context.xml`, bean with `myService` id):

```
<beans:bean id="myService" class="com.mycompany.serviceimpl.MyServiceImpl" />
```

Either remove the definition from XML or remove the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You *either* put `@Service` on `MyServiceImpl`, *or* you declare the bean in `Context.xml`. Don't do both, or you'll end up with two beans.

Remove the `myService` bean definition from the XML file, and you should be good to go.

Also, you shouldn't need to declare `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` or `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` beans - those are available by default.